# Can I assign two different environment variables for two different Java JDK?

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, windows-10

I have recently installed IntelliJ IDEA to my system and beside I use android studio too, but the android Gradle shows this error

"Project "project name" is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:

- Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
  spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
  while using Android Studio."

And Now I want to add Android OpenJDK location to Java_Home, There was already one I had set Amazon Corretto - JDK while installing IntelliJ IDEA.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: install sdkma if you are on *nix

Comment: No, I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: What's the problem to set the same JDK for both Android studio and IJ?

Comment: I am doing java programming with Amazon-Corretto, and android uses OpenJDK by default. Do you think is this a good idea to use Amazon-Corretto instead OpenJDK for android development? I thought maybe there are some specific customization on android default OpenJDK. I hope you got what I mean.